# Multiple CollectionDefinition per test class in XUnit

Tags: c#, xunit

We have many XUnit tests in our project that we use to test our API (each with many InlineData). The problem is that we can access a subset of the API via two other connection methods.
Today we use a CollectionDefinition to keep the connection to the main API (it is time consuming to create the connection) and we intend to have three separate `CollectionDefinition`, one for each connection path.

I imagine I will create a new attribute I can add to each test class to tell which connection methods it should use. And then it uses the CollectionDefinitions that are connected to the various connections.

I am considering using `[assembly: Xunit.TestFramework ("name", "assembly")]` and implementing my own `XunitTestFramework`. But I can not figure out how to achieve what I want. Do you have any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this as follows:

Make an abstract class that defines the methods common to all your API's, and derive specific classes from it which create the specific connection. Make a `CollectionDefinition` and a fixture for each type of connection:

```
using Xunit;

namespace SO71300821_multipleCollectionDefinition
{
    public abstract class APIConnectionMethod 
    {
        public bool isOK { get; } = true;
    };

    public class APIConnectionMethod0 : APIConnectionMethod
    {
        public APIConnectionMethod0()
        {
            // ... initialize API connection ...
        }
    }

    [CollectionDefinition("Collection0")]
    public class Collection0 : ICollectionFixture<APIConnectionMethod0>
    {
        // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
        // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
        // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
    }

    public class APIConnectionMethod1 : APIConnectionMethod
    {
        public APIConnectionMethod1()
        {
            // ... initialize API connection ...
        }
    }

    [CollectionDefinition("Collection1")]
    public class Collection1 : ICollectionFixture<APIConnectionMethod1>
    {
        // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
        // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
        // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
    }

    public class APIConnectionMethod2 : APIConnectionMethod
    {
        public APIConnectionMethod2()
        {
            // ... initialize API connection ...
        }
    }

    [CollectionDefinition("Collection2")]
    public class Collection2 : ICollectionFixture<APIConnectionMethod2>
    {
        // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
        // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
        // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
    }
}
```

Make an abstract base test class that implements all the tests that need to work for each of the various API's:

```
using Xunit;

namespace SO71300821_multipleCollectionDefinition
{
    public abstract class UnitTestBase
    {
        APIConnectionMethod connection;

        public UnitTestBase(APIConnectionMethod connection_)
        {
            connection = connection_;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void connectionIsOK()
        {
            Assert.NotNull(connection);
            Assert.True(connection.isOK);
        }

    }
}
```

Derive a public class from the base test class for each type of connection:

```
using Xunit;

namespace SO71300821_multipleCollectionDefinition
{
    [Collection("Collection0")]
    public class UnitTestSpecific0 : UnitTestBase
    {
        public UnitTestSpecific0(APIConnectionMethod0 connection_) : base(connection_)
        {
        }
    }

    [Collection("Collection1")]
    public class UnitTestSpecific1 : UnitTestBase
    {
        public UnitTestSpecific1(APIConnectionMethod1 connection_) : base(connection_)
        {
        }
    }

    [Collection("Collection2")]
    public class UnitTestSpecific2 : UnitTestBase
    {
        public UnitTestSpecific2(APIConnectionMethod2 connection_) : base(connection_)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If there are tests that only work for certain specific types of connections, you can implement them in these classes.

The test discoverer will find the tests in `UnitTestBase` in each of the derived classes and run them in those classes, so you'll have a separate test in the Test Explorer for each of the derived classes.

The information from https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context helped me prepare this answer and some of the code is copied from there.